# How to iterate over array of objects in PHP? With object method, class static method?

Tags: php, oop, static, iterator, iteration

I need to check to see if *any* object in an array of objects contains a certain variable value.

I.E. if `$object_array` contains 15 `$object` objects, I want to know if even one of them have their `$type` property set to `$some_type`.
The internals of the function aren't really that important since it accesses the public `get` method of the `$object`. I could use foreach, or array_walk, or whatever. The crux of my question is, where do I put this method?

The function would look like this:

```
public function hasSomeType($object_array,$some_type) {
    foreach($object_array as $object) {
      if($object->get('type') == '$some_type') {
        return true;
      }         
    }
    return false;
}
```

All of the tested objects would have a $type property accessible by their public `get` methods.

Where should I put this method? Should I make it a static method of the `$object`'s class?

Or should I create a new class, and use one of its objects to perform this operation.

I'm extremely unfamiliar with PHP's built-in constructs like "Iterator" and how they are used. I have no idea if they apply to my situation or not. I would greatly appreciate any help I can get.

Thank you.

EDIT:
Note I fixed the function above. Put "return false" in the right place and put the function signature in.

EDIT2: Changed function name and added `$some_type` argument to hopefully make it more clear that I am checking the `$type` property for some value. The question, though, is still "Where do I put this method"?

Comment: Put it into a utility class as a static method. Maybe sometime php will have extension methods and native linq support.

Comment: I'm probably leaning toward putting it in a helper.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Because it is a scope sensitive operation, putting it inside, or outside the class will yield diff results, if inside the class, private members are in scope. If outside, you're limited to what's visible.

Breaking it out simply to explain the idea:

```
class Bar {

   public function check( $type = 'int' ) {
       $vars = get_object_vars( $this );
       foreach( array_values( $vars ) as $v )
           if( stristr( $v, $type ) !== FALSE )
              return true;

       return false;
   }
}
```

If your classes all extended Bar for example, or implemented that function 'check', you could pass what you're looking for.  Using your code:

```
function checkArrayOfObjects( $object_array = array() )
{
    foreach($object_array as $object)
        if( is_object( $object ) /*&& $object instanceof Bar*/ && $object->check('int') )
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Note in your initial code, it would have only checked the first object ;)

Good luck.

Also, if you oversimplified your question, take a peek at PHP's ReflectionClass  https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php

*Code from comment below*

```
public function hasVarchar($object_array) { 
    foreach($object_array as $object) { 
        $vars = get_object_vars( $object ); 
        foreach( array_values( $vars ) as $v ) 
            if( stristr( $v, 'string') !== FALSE ) 
                return true; 
        }
        return false; 
     }
}
```

Comment: Yeah but the function I gave as an example takes the object array as an argument and uses the objects' public "get" method to obtain the information. Scope doesn't really matter since I'm only using public methods.

Comment: As to your note, yes I had "return false" in the wrong place and forgot to put in the function signature. I fixed it, so now it should be more clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Hey. All the right parts are in place, and knowing that you only use public makes it very simple.  You'd tweak your function like so: `public function hasVarchar($object_array) {
    foreach($object_array as $object) {
       $vars = get_object_vars( $object );
       foreach( array_values( $vars ) as $v )
           if( stristr( $v, 'string') !== FALSE )
              return true;
    }
    return false;
}`    Just remember, there's no such thing as varchar on a member, PHP will autobox the variable you assign to any of its class members, quietly.  That's why we use stristr to check 'string'

Comment: Guess I was shooting for that unsung badge here ;)

Comment: Wow, your new function is bewilderingly pointless! You have me checking each property of the object to see see if "string" is *part* of the variable's string value. My function is already fine. It checks *ONE* property, $type, for a particular string value. Your function would probably result in hundreds of errors since not all properties are strings. Most importantly, that's not addressing my question at all. My function is fine, I just want to know where to put it in an OOP context. In a new class? In a standalone function? In a helper class?

Comment: Just fueling a bad fire, but it's stronger than me. I was breaking code out verbosely to help you learn; clear you're new at PHP (don't mean this condescendingly - but your code isn't 'fine' as writ).  Contextual help requires that you explain why you need this; is it a usage pattern across one or many classes in your fabric.  Different contractual responsibilities?  As to your last comment, it was clearly fueled by a lack of understanding; the runtime is same as than the code in the question [both n*O(k)|k=#prop,n=#obj], won't throw errors. Why post here if not to learn?  Good luck Butkus.